# Invoking timed tasks in asynchronous Jax-RS requests

Tags: asynchronous, jms, jax-rs

I've joined a project that uses Jax-RS (and originally there was quite a bit of Spring-based Controller code in there too, but all URL handlers use Jax-RS now). Now we want to be able to fill in a queue of tasks that should be run with a small delay between each of them. The delay can be specified in ms. I've avoided Thread.sleep, as I've heard you should not manage threads manually in Java EE. Before I came in there was already a busy wait loop implemented.

I would like to switch this to an asynchronous background task. I could of course let the client poll the server with the given delay, and just have an AsyncResponse that can be resumed. But can the same AsyncResponse be resumed/suspended multiple times? The resource does have state, so it would be possible to drop the asynchrony completely and just do client polling to handle all of it.

A lot of example code for showing off asynchronous tasks use Thread.sleep. How bad is it to do this in a background task on an ExecutorService or something similar?

The point of the delay is to simulate human interaction, and post a long list of JMS messages to a queue but ensure that two listeners don't pick up and handle messages that depend on one another.

Is it easier/better to handle this on the client side rather than the server side? Writing some JavaScript that handles all the polling would be quite simple, so if this seems like a bad idea for handling on the server side, it's not that big a deal.

Answer (score 0):

The tool is only going to be used by a single user, as it's a developer testing tool. Therefore we went for solving this on the client side, pushing the messages onto the queue through AJAX calls. This works fine for our purposes, but if anyone has a solution that might help someone else. Feel free to drop a new answer.